# Python Multiprocessing Process seems to stop before doing anything

Tags: python, multithreading

I am having issues with multiprocessing.process - when targeting it at a simple function, is seems like this function is not getting executed. Running this:

```
import multiprocessing, time

def f(length):
    time.sleep( length )

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(1000,))
p.start()
time.sleep(0.5)
print( p, p.is_alive() )
```

returns

```
<Process(Process-5, stopped[1])> False
```

Using built-in time.sleep on the other hand is working:

```
import multiprocessing, time

p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=time.sleep, args=(1000,))
p2.start()
time.sleep(0.5)
print( p2, p2.is_alive() )
```

gives

```
<Process(Process-6, started)> True
```

I am using Spyder 2.3.7/Python 3.5.0 64bits on Windows Sever 2012.

Comment: I think on Windows you need to guard your top-level code in an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: just an FYI, on my mac, this code runs just fine

Comment: Blckknght: Afaik this applies only if imported elsewhere, which I am not doing here